# Header and Footer keep showing up with modal pop up window

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I just want to show basic HTML without the header and footer of my main page when using a modal window.
How can one do that in MVC3/4?

Here is an example of what is happening...
[image: Header and footer appearing in Modal Window]

Not sure why it is doing that.
This is a basic jquery modal window call

```
$(function () {
        //$('a.tempDlg').live("click", function (event) { loadDialog(this, event, '#edit-set'); });
        //$('a.AddPatDlg').live("click", function(event) {loadDialog(this, event, '#addPat');});
        //debugger;
        $('a.addEncounter').live("click", function (event) { loadDialog(this, event, '#DisplayUniqueEncounters'); });
        $('a.SearchEncounter').live("click", function (event) { loadDialog(this, event, '#searchEncounter'); });
        //$("#sID").click(function (event) { loadDialogByClick(this, event, '#searchEncounter'); });

    });
function loadDialog(tag, event, target) {
            //debugger;
            event.preventDefault();
            var $loading = $('<img src="<%=Url.Content("~/Images/ajax-loader.gif")%>" alt="loading" class="ui-loading-icon">');
            var $url = $(tag).attr('href');
            var $title = $(tag).attr('title');
            var $dialog = $('<div></div>');
            $dialog.empty();
            $dialog
            .append($loading)
            .load($url)
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: false
                   , title: $title
                   , width: 1200
                   , modal: true
                   , minHeight: 550
                   , show: 'fade'
                   , hide: 'fade'
            });

            $dialog.dialog('open');
        };
```

I have done this before without including the header and footer, and I forget how it was done?  I must be missing a step.

Comment: You need to return a `PartialView` from your controller action instead of the complete `View`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also set the Layout = null at the top of the page

Answer (score 0):

That is correct... I want to give nemesv credit for this answer, but he didn't answer the question.  So I will just say that he was right.  You need to return a partialView(), not just a regular view... Returning a regular view always gets all of the other MVC markup. Thanks...